# ReactiveUI vs. MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross, reactiveui

Title says it all. Based on your experience, what's the key difference between both frameworks?.
When we should use one over the other?.

Intended use: cross-platform development (Windows 8, iOS, Android, WindowsRT, Mac).

Answer (score 12):

I use both MvvmCross and ReactiveUI, in the same cross-platform solution, for iOS, Android, and Windows.

I would say my solution is based on MvvmCross because the App class, how the app starts up, and ViewModel navigation are following MvvmCross' way. But I also use several of  ReactiveUI's key features:

1. `ReactiveCommand`

I really like its auto disabling feature (CanExecute, IsExecuting) when it's bound to a button.

2. `ReactiveList` and it's derived list

This is a class that I would like to recommend to anyone programming MVVM, it has solved almost all my pain points in ObservalbeCollection. The usage of `CreateDerivedCollection` itself alone can be the whole reason that I include ReactiveUI in my project.

3. `MessageBus`

I'm afraid that I was spoiled by its auto marshaling to UI main thread. I don't need to worry if I'm in a task pool or UI thread, I just call SendMessage. (This is very different from MvvmLight's implementation and it's the main reason I left MvvmLight 2 years ago, sorry)

When I use the features above, I don't care if they're reactive or not, I just use them because they fit my needs very well. (In fact, `ReactiveCommand`, `ReactiveList`, and `MessageBus` are all reactive)

Can I use ReactiveUI only? I also asked the question to myself. I guess I will miss something from MvvmCross:

1. MvvmCross Plugins.

I use several plugins from MvvmCross and I really want each plugin is compatible with both MvvmCross and ReactiveUI. ( Maybe they already are, I just didn't check because I'm already using MvvmCross to handle the plugins.)

2. MvvmCross's tutorials

There are a lot of tutorial on MvvmCross and Youtube videos. I just can't image how much effort is put on those kinds of things.

I learn Xamarin by MvvmCross, to be honest.

3. MvvmCross's integration with Xamarin

Sometimes I can't tell if a class is provided by MvvmCross or Xamarin if not for the `Mvx` prefix. I checked my project, almost all the base classes of my UI code are MvxSomething (I don't use Xamarin.Forms). I don't know what exactly are provided by the Mvx version of the base classes, I just use them and they work.

I'm still learning both of the 2 frameworks, but I wish they can be merged one day.

Comment: How do you bind command with ReactiveUI in MvvmCross? I know how to add command in view model, but don't know how to add binding in view

Comment: @Felix Do you have an example project that combines MvvmCross with ReactiveUI?

Answer (score 11):

> But this isn't exclusive - ReactiveUI can be used with not-reactive code

Even further, you can use ReactiveUI alongside other MVVM frameworks, you don't need to commit to one or the other. Many methods in RxUI such as `WhenAny` work on any object and determine at runtime how to best connect to them.

RxUI is definitely a Buffet Table (take what you want!), not a seven-course meal :)  MvvmCross is certainly a great choice to base your app on, and it'd be awesome to have a team try out how they work together in the same app. Report back!

Answer (score 10):

> What's the key difference between both frameworks?

One is centred on the Reactive extensions, one is based on more conventional Mvvm coding.

But this isn't exclusive - ReactiveUI can be used with not-reactive code, and MvvmCross can be used with the reactive extensions.

> When we should use one over the other?

They are both great frameworks (IMO).

The choice of whether to use a framework and which to use is down to you and your team really.